# Navigate to same view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swiftui

So I'm trying to navigate from one view to another in SwiftUI and have stumbled upon a problem.

My views looks like this and trying to navigation from one DetailView to another DetailView but as soon I push the navigation link I'm forced back to the first DetailView.

Any ideas on how to achieve navigation to the same view in SwiftUI?

**ListView.swift**

```
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(data: data)) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailView.swift**

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(data: otherData)) {
                Text("Navigate")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Remove the `NavigationView` in `DetailView` as pointed out below but still facing the same issue.

Comment: It's working 100% fine for me. This is a link showing it works for me. Please tell me if what I am seeing is wrong: https://imgur.com/nMDDvuq

Comment: So weird. Perhaps something with my simulator...

Comment: Possibly, I ran the code using xCode 11.3 (11C9). It could be an xcode bug.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `NavigationView` from `DetailView`, there should be only one in stack, so when you navigate all new links are opened in original `NavigationView`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
         VStack {
             NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(data: otherData)) {
                 Text("Navigate")
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Removed, didn' resolved the issue though. As soon as I try to navigate from the DetailView the second time I get forced back again. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ismailp, I tested this code before posting answer. Have you tried it as posted or you have different real code?

Comment: which Xcode version do you have? I tested with Xcode 11.2 and Xcode 11.4beta3

Comment: I'm running 11.3.1

Comment: Could you test on real device? There is known issue navigation view for Xcode 11.3.1 in Preview/Simulator.

Comment: Yeah, will do that and get back to you with results.